# How to increment a sql DB from php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL DB that is just one table with one row that I would like to increment from my iphone, just to test out communication with a server.

I have done this with the phone before but I have never done the stuff on there server side and would like to learn.

so far I have created the sql db as said above. it is pretty much just this.

```
CREATE TABLE workers
(
id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
)
```

that could be slightly wrong.. it took me a couple of times to get it to work on the server and I am only writing it from memory now.

However now I would like to figure out how to just make it increment from a php script on my server... so far for the script I have done the basic stuff you do to get it to check for the DB connectivity so it looks a little something like this..

```
<?PHP
$con = mysql_connect("db.url.com","pass","username");
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("db", $con);

?>
```

I am not sure what to do now.. I would guess its some type of insert statment, but im not sure of this as I am using Auto Increment on that row...

any help would be greatly appreciated.. hopefully once I have had help figuring this out I will be able to move on and do more complex things myself :)

Comment: You want to increment the value in _one row_ or you want to add rows with an incrementing value for each (that's the purpose of `AUTO_INCREMENT`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql connection:

```
<?php 
$hostname = "yourhostname";
$database = "yourdatabase";
$username = "youusername";
$password = "yourpasword@";
$conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname,$username,$password) or die();
mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or die(“ERROR ”.mysql_error());
?>
```

Then the INSERT:

```
<?php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO workers (id) VALUES (null)");
?>
```

Hope it helps! =D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have just one row in the table, with a value increasing on every call, do

```
CREATE TABLE workers (id INT);
INSERT INTO workers SET id=0; -- or whatever start value you want
```

Then for each increment run

```
UPDATE workers SET id=id+1;
```

If you want to have more than one row, with ever increasing `id` field, use

```
CREATE TABLE workers (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY); -- and other needed cols
```

And for every row do

```
INSERT INTO workers SET id=0; -- again and other fields
```

MySQL will not really set the field to 0, but to a new increased value.

Answer (score 1):

You can just ignore that column. For example for this table structure

```
CREATE TABLE workers
(
id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
```

you would just do:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO workers(name) VALUES('John Peters')");
```

and it will add that column automatically. Moreover, for every column that has NULL available or has a defined value set, you can skip them too and it would automatically assign NULL and the default value respectively.

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_INCREMENT means each successive row you insert has an incrementally higher id. All you should need is a primary key on the id column.

```
INSERT INTO `workers` (`id`) VALUES (1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = `id` + 1
```

This will insert a row if there are no rows, but if you've already inserted a row, increments the id.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO `workers` VALUES (NULL)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `workers` (id) VALUES (NULL)
```